# Link to a page and trigger ajax via the same button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a div button which triggers ajax and links to a page which the ajax is posting data to. I have the ajax working on click, but can't seem to get the link to work at all with it, all the ways I've tried to get the link working do nothing.

I have a div button:

```
<div class="cman shadow1" id="search_button" value="carSearch"/>
    Start Search
</div>
```

Which triggers:

```
function carSearch() 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'searchpost.php',
        data: 
        {
            mpg : $('.mpg').val()
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("success! "+$('.mpg').val());
        }
    });
}
```

Edit:

Feel I should mention that the page I wish to link to is atm:

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('cdb', $conn);

if(isset($_POST['mpg']))
{
    $mpg = (int)($_POST["mpg"]);        

header("Location: home.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

I wish to use this to gather all of the search fields the user enters to then load the search results page. The above code for it is just for testing right now.

I mention this as user @Doge suggested doing document.location.href = "searchpost.php" in the success handler of the ajax, this did cause the page to change but the page didn't run the isset and the redirect, so the js variable wasn't posted, or it was but this instance of the page didn't get it.

The isset and redirect do work as using the XHR Network tab on my page the page it is to redirect to appears.

Comment: you can't redirect AND send an ajax request at the same time. you have to first wait for the ajax request to finish the "sending" portion. (Why does your div have an href attribute? a value attribute? a type attribute?)

Comment: If you redirect while an ajax request is still loading the request will be cancelled. Redirect in the success handler of your ajax call. (`document.location.href = "searchpost.php"`). Note that this will be a `GET` request.

Comment: div as type button? its won't work use input type="submit" or <button> tag and give id , then use onClick event.

Comment: @KevinB Well, the href was just testing to try and get the link working, as you can see in the actual div it isn't there. The value attribute is to trigger the ajax... and the type is actually left over from when the button wasn't calling ajax, removed it now.

Comment: @Doge Using (document.location.href = "searchpost.php") in the success handler did cause the page to redirect, but page it redirects to has an isset and a handler for the variable being posted from the ajax, and it isn't triggering. Yet looking at the XHR network tab on the previous page shows the page it is meant to redirect to when I click the button (without the success redirect)

Comment: If you want to display the result of `searchpost.php` from the ajax request then don't use an ajax request. If you make a regular `POST` request you will get the redirect for free. I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you trying to do, take input val and pass it to other page?

Comment: @Doge The values the ajax is posting are from jQuery, so I don't see any other way of getting these values to PHP.

Comment: @Ravg Yup, the values are js and I need them to use in a database search, so I gotta get them as PHP so I can apply them to a mysql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must do this via js then create a hidden form, populate it and submit it:

html:

```
<form method="post" id="hiddenform" action="searchpost.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="mpg" id="mpg"/>
</form>
```

js:

```
function carSearch() 
{ 
    $('#mpg').val(yourjsvariable);
    $('#hiddenform').submit();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is meant to help me. I'm not doing this via js through choice, the variables I'm posting are from jquery I have no other way of getting these variables to PHP to use in mysql apart from with ajax. I just wanna have a button that posts the jquery values to a page that I get linked to at the same time so I can actually make use of the variables.

Comment: @Tom Which is exactly what this does - it puts the js variable (called 'yourjsvariable' in my example) into a hidden field in an invisable form, then submits the form, which will both post the data and redirect - exactly what you asked for. Please comment if you have more questions.

Comment: ooooh, sorry I'm very tired and still new to js in general. So I'd get rid of my current ajax and just have my button call the function you made? Would the hidden form need to go in the button div or does it not matter as it is tied to the js by the id.

Comment: @Tom yes thats correct, and yes the form can go anywhere in the html.

Comment: Awww yisss, works perfectly, I'd seen the js way you've done before while looking how to od this, but I've always been told and read that to get js values to php you need to use ajax; but oh well this works thank you.